# Find all resturants inside a city or town by overpass-turbo

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I have this query on overpass-turbo:

```
[out:json][timeout:900];
area["ISO3166-1"="AM"];
node(area)[place~"^(town|city)$"]['name:en'~"^Armavir"];
```

Now I want to find all restaurant nodes inside `Armavir`town so I added

```
foreach(
  node ["amenity"="restaurant"](area);
  out;
```

but the result is an empty element.

```
[out:json][timeout:900];
area["ISO3166-1"="AM"];
node(area)[place~"^(town|city)$"]['name:en'~"^Armavir"];
foreach(
  node ["amenity"="restaurant"](area);
  out;
);
```

what is my problem?

I also tried to find relation Id of the city :

```
[out:json];
area["ISO3166-1"="AM"]->.co;
area[name="Armavir"](area.co)->.city;
rel(area.a)[boundary=administrative][admin_level=5];
out ids;
```

to calculate area id and replace this id here `area["ISO3166-1"="AM"]` but its result is empty.

Answer (score 1):

It’s data issue: because Armavir is tagged as a node, you can’t use it with area - simply because a node does not describe the exact boundaries of a town.

Try to fix the mapping first, by introducing a way or relation with appropriate tagging, then try again.